# Can't see custom metrics after sending with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to add a custom metric in Google Analytics throw Google Tag Manager inside the events Category.

### 1 - Create custom metric some days ago in the admin area

[image]

### 2 - Create the following tag in GTM

[image]

### 3 - Test values in preview mode

As you can see, metric with index 1 is set.

Event has being created in category called **Categoria metrica**

[image]

### 4 - Publish the changes

I've not forgotten to publish the changes. I've checked data is being sent:

[image]

### 5 - Metrics are missing in Events in Google Analytics

In `Events`, **Categoria metrica**  is missing

#### Should I have to add some code?

I think this should work now with a constant value written directly in GTM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Metrics are not visible in your standard reports. You can only see them through Custom Reports. So create a new flat report with your event parameter (category, action, label) and then select your CM as the metric.

Comment: Thanks nyuen. I've realized about that a few time ago, but Cutom Reports are also empty. You can find more about this problem and propose a solution if you know it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676580/custom-reports-are-empty-in-google-analytics-receiving-data-from-google-tag-mana